# How to check for a struct in a collection of structs, by structural equality?

Tags: collections, rust, traits, equality

If I have a struct:

```
pub struct Test {
    val1: u8,
    val2: u8,
}
```

and I make a `vec!` of these like:

```
let a = Test{val1: 1, val2: 1};
let b = Test{val1: 1, val2: 2};
let c = Test{val1: 1, val2: 2};
let my_vec = vec![a, b];
```

How can I tell if `my_vec` contains a struct with the same values as c?

Comment: I think I just need to impl PartialEq...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vec` has a method, `contains`, for checking if it contains a particular value.  The method requires that the elements implement `PartialEq`, which you can automatically derive like this:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Test {
    val1: u8,
    val2: u8,
}
```

So now you can do:

```
assert!(my_vec.contains(&c));
```

If your collection gets large, this will be quite inefficient, since it will have to compare against every element until it finds one that matches. A `HashSet` would be more efficient, but comes with its own requirement that you need to implement `Eq` and `Hash` too. Luckily, those can usually be derived in the same way.

Comment: More precisely, the `contains()` method is defined for _slices_, and it is available for vectors by virtue of a deref coercion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to impl PartialEq and the eq method as stated in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html

```
pub struct Test {
    val1: u8,
    val2: u8,
}

impl PartialEq for Test {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Test) -> bool {
        self.val1 == other.val1 && self.val2 == other.val2
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Test{val1: 1, val2: 1};
    let b = Test{val1: 1, val2: 2};
    let c = Test{val1: 1, val2: 2};
    let my_vec = vec!(a, b);

    println!("{}", my_vec.contains(&c));
}
```

Comment: For this example, as for most cases, deriving is enough.